# How understand ++ cast expression in cpp?

Tags: c++

My understanding of the grammar *++ cast-expression* is as follows:

```
float p = 3.14;
++(int)p;
```

But when I compile it with clang, it fails to compile. So how do understand *++ cast-expression* and what is use for?  `(int)p` is a *cast-expression* so why doesn't it work?

[image: cpp-std-draft]

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

Comment: there is no type called `flaot` and the second line misses a `;`. What is the error you get (after fixing those typos)?

Comment: `(int)p` is not an lvalue.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "++ cast", what you have is a [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) and a pre-increment operation, that is not one operation.

Comment: @CoryKramer I don't think OP calls `++` a cast. The grammar says `++` can be *followed by* a cast, and OP asks when it can happen.

Comment: Edited to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you got me.
@ NathanOliver thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++(int)p` fails to compile because `(int)p` is not an l-value. However, that's a semantic error, not a syntactic one. Syntactically it's valid and matches the `++ cast-expression` production.

An instance where `++` followed by a cast would be both syntactically and semantically valid would be when you cast to a reference (references being l-values). An example (albeit not a useful one) would be:

```
int x = 42;
++(int&)x;
```

In practice the `cast-expression` in `++ cast-expression` will rarely be an actual cast. In most cases, `cast-expression` will be further reduced to `primary-expression`, allowing you to match expressions like `++x`.

Comment: more plausible example: `void dangerous(const int & x) { ++(int &)x; }`

Comment: Just one more reason to avoid C style casts.  A `static_cast` would trigger an error.